# Apply css after inserting javascript elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div called "thumbs" and a javascript function populating it with images

```
function fillThumbs(){
    for (i=0; i<images.length; i++){
    var imageX = document.createElement("img");
    imageX.src = images[i];
    document.getElementById("thumbs").appendChild(imageX);
    }

}
```

then my css code

```
#thumbs{
margin: 0 auto;
}

#thumbs img{
width: 220px;
margin: 0 10 10 0;
}
```

Problem: thumbs div is not centered, nor the #thumbs img are correctly spaced out. Looks like the margin property is ignored, while the width of the images is
correctly passed.

Comment: jsfiddle my friend would be so nice

Comment: `#thumbs { text-align: center; }` should work

Comment: Margin:0 10 10 0 -> Margin:0 10px 10px 0;

Comment: You need to specifiy a *unit* for your margin in addition to the *values*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The margins aren't being applied because you don't have any units on them. You need `px` or similar (on the values that aren't 0; CSS is fine with 0s with no units):

```
#thumbs{
margin: 0 auto;
}

#thumbs img{
width: 220px;
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
/*          ^^   ^^     */
}
```

**Live Example**:

```js
var i;
function fillThumbs(){
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    var imageX = document.createElement("img");
    imageX.src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e459e3d0f28452212c5958e54f658ef8?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG";
    document.getElementById("thumbs").appendChild(imageX);
    }

}
fillThumbs();
```

```css
#thumbs{
margin: 0 auto;
}

#thumbs img{
width: 220px;
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbs"></div>
```

Hint: To diagnose issues like this, right-click the element in your browser and choose "inspect element" (if you don't have that choice, use Chrome or Firefox). Use that, then look at the browser's dev tools to see why the CSS isn't being applied. Here's what Chrome's dev tools shows me:

[image]

and then if I hover the handy warning icon:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your should always provide a unit as soon as the value is not equal to 0. Change your css like:

```
#thumbs img{
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

The `margin: 0 auto;` will only center the #thumbs node if it's width is known. Try giving it a width.